# Swift - extensions & protocol - "super" function not called

Tags: swift, protocols

I have the following code:

```
protocol Viewable
{
    func didAwakeFromNib()
    func foo()
}

extension Viewable where Self:UIView
{
    func didAwakeFromNib()
    {
        // NOT CALLED!
        foo()
    }
}

protocol Fontable:Viewable
{
    func some1()
    func some2()
    func some3()
}

extension Fontable where Self:UIView
{
    func didAwakeFromNib()
    {
        some1()
        some2()
        some3()
    }
}

class UIButtonBase:UIButton,Fontable,Viewable //(Viewable Not necessary here because Fontable already conforms to Viewable)
{
        override func awakeFromNib()
        {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            didAwakeFromNib()
        }
}
```

As you can see i have 2 protocols with extension for each, and 1 class of `UIButtonBase`.

I'm new with Swift, and i want to know why my `func didAwakeFromNib()` at `Viewable` not called when i call `didAwakeFromNib()` in the button class. (`didAwakeFromNib()` at Fontable called as i expected).

Answer (score 0):

There are two definitions of `didAwakeFromNib()`

1. Defined in `Fontable` extension.
2. Defined in `Viewable` extension.

And `Fontable` protocol is extend from `Viewable`. In your above code `didAwakeFromNib()` definition in `Fontable` extension overrides the implementation and that's why `foo()` is not called.

As in your code `UIButtonBase` is implementing both `Fontable` and `Viewable` and `didAwakeFromNib` definition from `Fontable` is being called.

```
class UIButtonBase:UIButton, Fontable ,Viewable
```

So If you changed this to.

```
class UIButtonBase:UIButton ,Viewable
```

Now `didAwakeFromNib` from `Viewable` will be called and eventually `foo()` will be called.

Comment: Hey, first of all - thank. but i don't see the difference. because you wrote twice "class UIButtonBase:UIButton, Fontable ,Viewable". is that what you meant?

Comment: Now i see :). But i want to call the didAwakeFromNib from Viewable AND Fontable. Is it possible?